# Can't access Google Apps Marketplace SDK configuration

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have Gmail Contextual Gadget that is already deployed and is working. I did not visit its SDK for a while and today I realized that I cannot access Google Apps Marketplace SDK from the Developers Console anymore. When I select my project, click on APIs and click on a "gear" next to Google Apps Marketplace SDK - it shows me a page with several choices. "API Configuration" has link "Go to the original console", but it does nothing. Do I need to convert to something new?

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue.

I don't know a correct solution,
but you can go to the original console directry with the below link.(Please replace [projectno] with your project no.)

https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect&pli=1#project:[projectno]:googleapps_sdk

Comment: Thanks, Teruhisa - it worked perfectly. Where do you find those old API links?

Comment: Glad to hear that. Ah...in the browsing history. :)